# Xcode 9 Slowed To A Crawl

Tags: xcode, performance, xcode9

I updated my MacPro Core 2 duo, 4G Ram with a 500G SSD, installed High Siera, XCode 9 and Swift 4.  Everything was working fine for about a month.  I wouldn't say the machine was snappy but it was quick to the touch and very usable as a dev environment.

All of a sudden (possibly after an auto update as the machine rebooted on its own one night) XCode 9 became unbearably slow to the point its not usable any longer.  I researched on SO and other places; tried some things like renaming a plug in, deleting the workspace, rebooting, cleaning the project, switching to iPhone 10 simulator, etc but nothing worked.

From what I read even upgrading to 16G of ram and a faster machine does not fix the problem.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update - builds are still fast;  the problem seems to be with the Storybook editor;  its very slow on the open and when selecting different UI elements to make setting changes.

Comment: Why did you down vote this question as not being about programing?.  Its about the entire programing/development environment going south as it apparently has for many others.  How to efficiently develop an iOS app as well as the tools to use is very appropriate to a programing discussion.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you search "Xcode slow" on SO you will find over 1,600 similar questions; unfortunately not many answers.

Comment: Happens to me too, guess that's just how it is ‍♂️ – MBP 2015, 2.8GHZ i7, 16GBRAM

Comment: It is expected that after a macOS update, the machine could be slower for a few days. Not noticeable with some apps, but may impact others (depends on reading writing to disk).

Comment: The machine is fast enough outside of XCode. I uninstalled and reinstalled it and it worked fine for about 5 mins then same problem.

Comment: It's not about the updates. It's not even about using a beta of either Xcode or macOS, or even both. It's just that Apple isn't capable of making Xcode fast, or at least properly usable.

Comment: If not XCode then what else can be used to develop with Swift?

Comment: You could use [JetBrain's AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/?fromMenu). I've tried it, it's ok. But still, creating complex layouts is a pain in the *** without interface builder so I'm stuck with Xcode.

Comment: Every click or even a mouse over draws up the spinning beach ball.  It’s not usable in this state.  Maybe back to Objective C...

Comment: I actually had that behavior back in Swift 2.x. It happened if a file was too big. A class with over 6K lines would do that. You hit a key, it respond 15 seconds later. Unworkable. Interesting that it just started. Is it all the projects?

Comment: Yes, all projects.  This one is very small as I'm just starting it.  I also created a new project and the same thing happens.  My guess at this point is that its the story board editor.  I don't know how I'm going to develop apps given this environment.  It might also have something to do with an auto OS update because it happened after an update as evidenced by the auto reboot at night but I can't be 100%.

Comment: Update 1 -- So fortunately the project is just kicking off and I was able to save the project; erase the disk; reinstall High Sierra and Xcode; copy the project back over and open in XCode.  All is working well again.  I'm taking a snap shot with Time Machine just in case.  We'll see how things progress over the next few days.

Comment: Update Final - So all is well.  High Siear 10.13.4 and all updates applied and it still works fine.